# How do I make a basic App Engine Connected Android Project?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm new to this, so please bear with me. I simply want to get the basic App Engine Connected Android Project to work in eclipse.

I first downloaded Eclipse 3.7 and the Android SDK.  I installed the ADT plugin through eclipse. I configured eclipse to point to the sdk and created an android project.  I added some widgets, messed around with SMS messages, and ran it on my phone.  Worked like a charm.

Then I decided it was time to work with app engine.  I downloaded the Google plugin for eclipse from within eclipse using this link http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7.  I also downloaded the Google App Engine Java SDK from that link.

Ok, here's where it gets more fun.  I created a new app engine connected android project and named it "TestProjectThree".  I then clicked "Debug as->local app engine connected android project".  On the console I got a url, but on my phone I got a black screen.  I then noticed that there was nothing in the android/gen folder, so I did a clean build of both projects.  Suddenly, it gave me 10 warnings.

> "Cannot fully validate context since domain type com.testprojectthree.server.HelloWorldService is not available.
>
> You must run the ValidationTool as part of your server build process."

I googled the problem and found this link http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation.

I began following the instructions.  I tried to enable annotation processing, but it was already enabled.  I tried to add the requestfactory-apt.jar to the factory path, but it was already there too.

Apparently now I need to run something called an Annotation Processor.  I've never used Maven before but I right click on my android project->configure->convert to Maven project.  I do a clean build and a POM file appears.  I then copy all of the XML from that link to the line right above the /project line in the POM file.  I copy the second bit too because I'm using indigo.  Clean and build again.  New error.

> "/TestProjectThree-Android/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it."

No idea what that one means either, but I see right click gen->build path->convert to source folder so I click that too.  Clean and build again. NO ERRORS!! YAYAYAY!!!

Debug as local app engine connected android project.  Got a black screen on the phone, and some sort of error in eclipse.  “Source not found”.  Looked for a more detailed error message but the console just has the app engine url on it and logcat looks empty.

I went back to the link about the validation tool and read all the comments. A lot of people seemed confused.  I have no idea if I did it right, or did any of it right, and am very lost now.  Please please please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds very similar to a problem I had, although not exactly.

I think the code generated by the AppEngine project that is used by the Android project is either not generated correctly, or needs a refresh.....and clean doesn't do it.

Try this:

First, make sure the requestfactory-apt.jar was in the "Factory Path" of "Annotation Processing" in the "Java Compiler" section of Project Properties.

In AppEngine project.
Properties-> Java Build Path, Source section. Select the ".apt_generated" entry and then "edit…" and rename it, by putting a "1" at the end of the name (or whatever).
Project -> Clean

then in Android Project
Properties-> Java Build Path, Source section. 
Select the "apt_generated" source folder that is linked to the ".apt_generated" source folder in the AppEngine project.
"Edit…", then in the first line "Linked Folder Location" navigate to the NEWLY named folder in the AppEngine project (the one with the "1" at the end……)
Then Project -> Clean

Then build & run your Android project, it should now have newly generated RequestFactory code from AppEngine project and validate OK at runtime.

It's possible that closing and opening projects and cleans were also required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  In the AppEngine project, I renamed the .apt_generated entry just as you said.  However, when I build I get an error that says, "Generated source folder '.apt_generated' is missing from classpath".

Comment: In the android project, .apt_generated is not on the build path.  I can put it there by clicking "Add Folder" and then placing a check next to apt_generated.  However, when I click "Edit" it only gives me the option to change the name.  There was no "Linked Folder Location."  When I tried to "Link Source" and selected .apt_generated from the app engine project, it said I couldn't because the file already existed. When I tried "Link Source" and selected the .apt_generated1 from the app engine project, it successfully added.

Comment: However, it then gave me 17 errors.  

"com.google cannot be resolved to a type"
"OperationData cannot be resolved to a type"
"OperationKey cannot be resolved to a type"
"The import com.google cannot be resolved"

I can go to the error and it suggests the fix, "Fix project setup". If I click that, the fix is to add 'gwt-user.jar' to the build path. Doing this fixes all the errors, however when I try to run it still says "Source not found".

Comment: I edited the name in the AppEngine project - that seemed to regenerate the code, which is the source of the problem. Then in the Android project I had to delete the Linked Source folder (if it was there from the Build path, AND from the project), then open the Build Path again and re-add it....then it all worked. Doing this on other copies of the projects(s) fixed the problem "reliably" for me.

Comment: You had to do the validation described here http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation first right? I'm still struggling with that.

Comment: No, no validation. I just had to make sure the requestfactory-apt.jar  was in the "Factory Path" of "Annotation Processing" in the "Java Compiler" section of properties, and then fiddle with the name of the .apt_generated folder in the AppEngine project (source tab of build path) to get it re-renerated and the link to it in the Android project. I think closing and opening projects and cleans were also required.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help! :) Do you know when the validation might be required?

Comment: Glad I could help Adam. I updated the answer from the comments. I suspect the validator is to be used when you don't have connected projects, or have separate code trying to use the stuff generated.....but am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use parse. I tried using AppEnging for my app's backend, but parse seems to take care of a lot of backend jobs and makes life extremely easy https://parse.com